# Запрос и получение ответа от платежного шлюза через вспомогательный домен

Tags: запрос, интернет-магазин, шлюз

Есть два магазина. Соответственно два домена. К первому из этих доменов привязана учетная запись на платежном шлюзе. По определенным причинам второй магазин (соответственно и его домен) нельзя "светить" платежному сервису. Возможно ли в такой ситуации отправлять запросы и получать ответы от платежного шлюза для второго магазина так, чтобы платежный шлюз видел их как от первого домена? Если да, буду благодарен за небольшое описание процесса как это построить.